# MongoDb cluster sort method not working with different number of digit of an integer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, sorting

when i sort in my ui. if same number of digit of an integer it is working. if different number of digit of an integer it is not working.suppose evry number 3 digit it is working.but some 3 digit, some another digit it is not working. same for 2 digit if evry number 2 digit it is working.but some 2 digit, some another digit it is not working.
suppose it is working `[103,107,864,977]`. but `[103,54,862,7541]` it is not working

express js code

```
 app.get("/myToys/:email", async (req, res) => {
      const { sort } = req.query;
      const query = { sellerEmail: req.params.email };
      let sortOption = {};

      if (sort === "asc") {
        sortOption = { price: 1, _id: 1 };
      } else if (sort === "desc") {
        sortOption = { price: -1, _id: -1 };
      }

      try {
        const toys = await dollToys.find(query).sort(sortOption).toArray();

        res.send(toys);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to fetch toy data:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Failed to fetch toy data");
      }
    });
```

react code

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https:myapi/myToys/${user?.email}?sort=${sort}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setToys(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Failed to fetch toy data:", error);
      });
  }, [user, sort]);
```

Comment: can you provide your input data in collection and results you are getting?

Comment: Are the _"numbers"_ you are sorting on stored as strings?